# Problem occurred while installing e(fx)clipse using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I have Eclipse: Eclipse DSL Tools

Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0)

And I have that JDK:

Java SE Development Kit 8 Update 172

And I'm trying to install e(fx)clipse
via going in my Eclipse to: Help -> Install New Software ->

Adding one of these links:

```
    https://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/3.5.0/site/
    https://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/3.4.1/site/
    https://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/2.4.0/site/
```

But then I get this error:

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session
>   context was:(profile=epp.package.dsl,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
>   action=). No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.archetype.common,1.11.0.20190220-2117 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.binaryproject,1.11.0.20190220-2119 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.binaryproject.ui,1.11.0.20190220-2119 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.core,1.11.0.20190220-2119 No repository
>   found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui,1.11.0.20190220-2119 No repository
>   found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.discovery,1.11.0.20190220-2119 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.editor,1.11.0.20190220-2119 No repository
>   found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.editor.xml,1.11.0.20190220-2119 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.importer,1.11.0.20190220-2119 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.jdt,1.11.0.20190220-2119 No repository
>   found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.ui,1.11.0.20190220-2119 No repository
>   found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.launching,1.11.0.20190220-2119 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.lifecyclemapping.defaults,1.11.0.20190220-2119
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender,1.11.0.20190220-2119 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration,1.11.0.20190220-2119
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.maven.indexer,1.11.0.20190220-2117 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime,1.11.0.20190220-2117 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple,1.11.0.20190220-2117
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.model.edit,1.11.0.20190220-2119 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.profiles.core,1.11.0.20190220-2119 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.profiles.ui,1.11.0.20190220-2119 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.refactoring,1.11.0.20190220-2119 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.scm,1.11.0.20190220-2119 No repository
>   found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.sourcelookup,1.11.0.20190220-2119 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.sourcelookup.ui,1.11.0.20190220-2119 No
>   repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.m2e.feature,1.11.0.20190220-2119
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature,1.11.0.20190220-2119

What could cause the problem?
Any ideas how to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It can be repository down temporarily or install the latest eclipse and install this tool may work out for you.

Comment: Looks like it wants the Eclipse M2E plugins from the current 2019-03 version of Eclipse.

Comment: You can also try asking [here](https://github.com/eclipse-efx/efxclipse-eclipse/issues).

Comment: It is available through the regular eclipse update site. The last release is 3.3.0 and the sites you mention seem to contain preliminary releases.

Comment: @JensDibbern No, it was removed from the update site and the last release is 3.5.0. The update site in the question is correct.